# RecylerView items collapsed data to display

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which has items to display from REST API response when user choosed to load more data. However the data which binded to onBindViewHolder collapsed on the item. 
The collapsed data is shown in the image below:

[The orange and black text are come from different data list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv1E0.png)

The code to set data list to adapter when user choosed load more data:

```
 mAdapter = new MaterialsRecyclerView(username, datePost, contentPost,
                        userPicturePost, contentType, titlePost, contentLabel, activityLabel, numberFavorite,
                        numberUpvote, numberDownvote, numberComments, upvoteStatus, downvoteStatus, favoriteStatus, getActivity(),
                        newsType, newsMedia, contentId, activityType
                );

                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I tried

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after add data to data list in adapter but the data still collapsed.

My question is why collapsed data happened? And how to make the data not collapsed? I mean the data just loaded from data list suitable with the index.

**Edit**

Adapter class code(Constructor) method:

```
public MaterialsRecyclerView(List<String> usernameListParam, List<String> datePostListParam,
                             List<String> contentPostListParam, List<String> userPictureProfileListParam,
                             List<String> contentTypeListParam, List<String> titlePostListParam,
                             List<String> contentLabelListParam, List<String> activityLabelListParam,
                             List<Integer> textNumberFavoriteListParam, List<Integer> textNumberUpvoteListParam,
                             List<Integer> textNumberDownvoteListParam, List<Integer> textNumberCommentListParam,
                             List<Boolean> statusUpvotesParam, List<Boolean> statusDownvotesParam,
                             List<Boolean> statusFavoritesParam, Activity activity, List<Integer> newsTypeListParam,
                             List<String> newsMediaListParam, List<String> contentIdListParam,
                             List<Integer> activityCodeListParam) {

    this.activity = activity;
    usernameList = usernameListParam;
    datePostList = datePostListParam;
    contentPostList = contentPostListParam;
    userPictureProfileList = userPictureProfileListParam;
    contentTypeList = contentTypeListParam;
    titlePostList = titlePostListParam;
    contentTextList = contentLabelListParam;
    activityTextList = activityLabelListParam;
    textNumberDownvoteList = textNumberDownvoteListParam;
    textNumberUpvoteList = textNumberUpvoteListParam;
    textNumberFavoriteList = textNumberFavoriteListParam;
    textNumberCommentList = textNumberCommentListParam;
    statusUpvoteList = statusUpvotesParam;
    statusDownvoteList = statusDownvotesParam;
    statusFavoriteList = statusFavoritesParam;
    newsTypeList = newsTypeListParam;
    newsMediaList = newsMediaListParam;
    contentIdList = contentIdListParam;
    activityCodeList = activityCodeListParam;

    username = new String[usernameList.size()];
    datePost = new String[datePostList.size()];
    titlePost = new String[titlePostList.size()];
    contentPost = new String[contentPostList.size()];
    userPictureProfile = new String[userPictureProfileList.size()];
    contentType = new String[contentTypeList.size()];
    contentText = new String[contentTextList.size()];
    activityText = new String[activityTextList.size()];
    textNumberFavorite = new Integer[textNumberFavoriteList.size()];
    textNumberUpvote = new Integer[textNumberUpvoteList.size()];
    textNumberDownvote = new Integer[textNumberDownvoteList.size()];
    textNumberComment = new Integer[textNumberCommentList.size()];
    statusUpvote = new Boolean[statusUpvoteList.size()];
    statusDownvote = new Boolean[statusDownvoteList.size()];
    statusFavorite = new Boolean[statusFavoriteList.size()];
    newsType = new Integer[newsTypeList.size()];
    newsMedia = new String[newsMediaList.size()];
    contentId = new String[contentIdList.size()];
    activityCode = new Integer[activityCodeList.size()];

    username = usernameList.toArray(username);
    datePost = datePostList.toArray(datePost);
    titlePost = titlePostList.toArray(titlePost);
    contentPost = contentPostList.toArray(contentPost);
    userPictureProfile = userPictureProfileList.toArray(userPictureProfile);
    contentType = contentTypeList.toArray(contentType);
    contentText = contentTextList.toArray(contentText);
    activityText = activityTextList.toArray(activityText);
    textNumberFavorite = textNumberFavoriteList.toArray(textNumberFavorite);
    textNumberUpvote = textNumberUpvoteList.toArray(textNumberUpvote);
    textNumberDownvote = textNumberDownvoteList.toArray(textNumberDownvote);
    textNumberComment = textNumberCommentList.toArray(textNumberComment);
    statusUpvote = statusUpvoteList.toArray(statusUpvote);
    statusDownvote = statusDownvoteList.toArray(statusDownvote);
    statusFavorite = statusFavoriteList.toArray(statusFavorite);
    newsType = newsTypeList.toArray(newsType);
    newsMedia = newsMediaList.toArray(newsMedia);
    contentId = contentIdList.toArray(contentId);
    activityCode = activityCodeList.toArray(activityCode);

    //notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Adapter xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/putih"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_margin="8dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/label_color_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/news_dashboard_mark"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/label_color_material"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/material_dashboard_mark"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_picture"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="right"
                android:layout_below="@+id/label_color_news"
                android:src="@drawable/recycleview_user" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username_label"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/user_picture"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_picture"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/abu"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username_activity_label"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/user_picture"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/username"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/abu"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/info_button_content_activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/username"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_post"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:text="@string/date_label"
                android:layout_below="@+id/username"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_picture"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/abu"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_label"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout_not_news_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/material_author_label"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_activity_desc"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativelayout_not_news_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/date_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_content_desc"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_activity_desc"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/material_author_label"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout_not_news_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:visibility="gone">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_post"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/post_title_label"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/oranyeTerang"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content_post"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/post_content_label"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_post"
                android:textColor="@color/abu"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout_news_admin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_post_news_admin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/oranyeTerang"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/post_title_label"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content_post_news_admin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="@string/post_content_label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title_post_news_admin"
                    android:textColor="@color/abu"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout_news_nonadmin_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_post_news_nonadmin_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="@string/post_title_label"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/oranyeTerang"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content_post_nonadmin_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/post_content_label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title_post_news_nonadmin_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/abu"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout_news_nonadmin_media"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/media_post_news_nonadmin_media"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/abu"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/caption_post_news_nonadmin_media"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="@string/post_title_label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/media_post_news_nonadmin_media"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/abu"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_numbers_favorite"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_number_favorite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_numbers_upvote"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_numbers_upvote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_numbers_downvote"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_numbers_downvote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_comments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0 Komentar"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/awan"></View>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondary_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_favorite"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_18dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_comment"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_outline_black_18dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_upvote"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_downvote"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

POJO class which used as a data object model:

```
public class DashboardPOJO {
@SerializedName("rc")
public String rc;

@SerializedName("rm")
public String rm;

@SerializedName("skip")
public int skip;

@SerializedName("access_token")
public String access_token;


public DashboardPOJO(int skip, String access_token) {
    this.skip = skip;
    this.access_token = access_token;
}

public String getRm() {
    return rm;
}

@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<DashboardPOJO.Results> results = null;

public List<DashboardPOJO.Results> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public class Results{
    @SerializedName("dashboard")
    @Expose
    private Dashboard dashboard;

    public class Dashboard {
        @SerializedName("content_id")
        @Expose
        private String id;

        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        private String title;

        @SerializedName("desc")
        @Expose
        private String desc;

        @SerializedName("synopsis")
        @Expose
        private String synopsis;

        @SerializedName("content_code")
        @Expose
        private Integer content_code;

        @SerializedName("activity_code")
        @Expose
        private Integer activityCode;

        @SerializedName("post_by")
        @Expose
        private PostBy postBy;

        @SerializedName("user_detail")
        @Expose
        private UserDetail userDetail;

        @SerializedName("files")
        @Expose
        private List<DashboardPOJO.Results.Dashboard.Files> files = null;

        @SerializedName("activity_text")
        @Expose
        private String activityText;

        @SerializedName("content_text")
        @Expose
        private String contentText;

        @SerializedName("news_type")
        @Expose
        private int newsType;

        @SerializedName("upvote")
        @Expose
        private int upvote;

        @SerializedName("downvote")
        @Expose
        private int downvote;

        @SerializedName("favorite")
        @Expose
        private int favorite;

        @SerializedName("upvoted")
        @Expose
        private boolean upvoted;

        @SerializedName("downvoted")
        @Expose
        private boolean downvoted;

        @SerializedName("favorited")
        @Expose
        private boolean favorited;

        @SerializedName("comment")
        @Expose
        private int comment;

        @SerializedName("created_at_from_now")
        @Expose
        private String createdAt;

        public String getId(){
            return id;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        public String getSynopsis() {
            return synopsis;
        }

        public Integer getContent_code() {
            return content_code;
        }

        public Integer getActivityCode() {
            return activityCode;
        }

        public String getActivityText() {
            return activityText;
        }

        public String getContentText() {
            return contentText;
        }

        public int getNewsType() {
            return newsType;
        }

        public int getUpvote() {
            return upvote;
        }

        public int getDownvote() {
            return downvote;
        }

        public int getFavorite() {
            return favorite;
        }

        //
        public boolean getUpvoted() {
            return upvoted;
        }

        public boolean getDownvoted() {
            return downvoted;
        }

        public boolean getFavorited() {
            return favorited;
        }

        public int getComment() {
            return comment;
        }

        public String getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt;
        }

        public PostBy getPostBy() {
            return postBy;
        }

        public UserDetail getUserDetail() {
            return userDetail;
        }

        public void setPostBy(PostBy postBy) {
            this.postBy = postBy;
        }

        /*@SerializedName("results")
        @Expose
        private List<DashboardPOJO.Results> results = null;

        public List<DashboardPOJO.Results> getResults() {
            return results;
        }*/

        public List<DashboardPOJO.Results.Dashboard.Files> getFiles() {
            return files;
        }

        public class Files {
            @SerializedName("originalname")
            @Expose
            private String originalName;

            @SerializedName("filename")
            @Expose
            private String filename;

            @SerializedName("http_path")
            @Expose
            private String httpPath;

            public String getHttpPath() {
                return httpPath;
            }

            public String getOriginalName() {
                return originalName;
            }

            public String getFilename() {
                return filename;
            }
        }

        public class UserDetail {
            @SerializedName("display_picture")
            @Expose
            private String displayPicture;

            public String getDisplayPicture() {
                return displayPicture;
            }
        }

        public class PostBy {

            @SerializedName("user_id")
            @Expose
            private String userId;
            @SerializedName("username")
            @Expose
            private String username;

            public String getUserId() {
                return userId;
            }

            public void setUserId(String userId) {
                this.userId = userId;
            }

            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }

            public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
            }

        }
    }

    public Dashboard getDashboard() {
        return dashboard;
    }
}}
```

Comment: i think in your adapter has some mistake. provide your adapter class code.

Comment: you have problems with your item layout

Comment: Please check the question again, I've provided the snippet code. @AndroidTeam

Comment: Why you said there are problems with the item layout? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: because the screenshot looks like you have misplaced the views of the list item in it's xml - they all are on top of each other.

Comment: In adapter layout has some mistake there for value are collapsed each other. provide your adapter layout xml code.

Comment: and also all information take in one pojo class and only pass that pojo class in adapter constructor as list.

Comment: Please check the snipped code in question section. Already updated. @AndroidTeam

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you have several views with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/user_picture"
```

so they are drawn on top of each other

Comment: yes but for initial I set the several views with visibility gone and display (visibility:visible) the view based on the conditional.

Comment: Go to Tools->Layout Inspector, there you can figure out exactly which views are overlapping and then look closely into their parameters